# Swift 1.2 closure optimisation bug

Tags: swift, release-mode

I have an array of objects which all have a timeStamp (NSDate) and I am trying to sort them with the closure below.

The problem is that this works well without any optimisation, so with debug builds all is fine and dandy. But in with optimisations I get the following EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

[image: The closure simply won't work with optimisation..]

```
        reportCells.sort({ (a: UITableViewCell, b: UITableViewCell) -> Bool in
        if let first = a as? GreenelyTableViewCell,
            second = b as? GreenelyTableViewCell {
                if let firstDate = first.timeStamp,
                    secondDate = second.timeStamp {
                        let comparison = firstDate.compare(secondDate)
                        if comparison == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                }
        }
        return false
    })
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: copy your code here so that  I may edit it. Don't post picture

Comment: There added code to the question..

Comment: In what context are you sorting table view cells? And what do you want to do with these resorted cells? You really shouldn't be maintaining external references to table view cells. That's likely to screw up the table view cell dequeueing logic. If you want to sort, you should sort the model data backing table, not the cells themselves, and then  `reloadData` if you want to reflect this in the table.

Comment: The sorted cells are shown in the tableview. They need to be sorted by date (it's a kind of news feed). The context is that it fetches data (via a 3 level deep completion block)..

The lines above and below the closure can be ignored it was just try from earlier. I do reload the tableview data when it's sorted. I will rewrite the structure as you said, the main issue now is the closure. :/

I also tried to call the sorting closure in the context of a method, which gave me the same problems.

Comment: Attempting to sort cells reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of how table views work. E.g., a table with 100 rows, for which only 10 are visible, there should be only 10 cells in memory and the table view will reuse them as it sees fit. You should not be maintaining arrays of cells. You don't own these cell objects; the table view does. You should not use cells to hold/maintain model data. When sorting table, you shouldn't sort the cells, but rather sort your separate model objects and the call `reloadData`. You are using tableview cells in a context for which they're not designed.

Comment: Ok entalpi sorry for late. See answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are sorting the cells. Which is not a proper approach first of all. You should sort your data source array. Because table is managing its cells in memory and when you make an array of cells. It will cause issues in backend even if it seems working. Now coming to your problem,

You are sorting cells and when you get back to the tableview listing methods, it agains fetches the data from data source i mean your array of objects. And tableview don't finds proper arrangements of data. I mean your cells are in 1 , 4, 2, 3 order after your sort while your data is stil in 1,2,3,4 order. This will cause table view to throw exception. More over, cells resulebility will cause also issue. **So for your is to sort your data before showing it to cell. And I bet your problem will be resolved.**